# A faster way to combine a large number of datasets in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I've run into the problem of combining a large number of datasets in R (858, to be precise) and wrote a couple lines of code to solve this as memory efficient as possible. The code below is working, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way of doing this. While working fine and memory use being stable, the process does slow down considerably with every dataset being added. Past 350 or so, it becomes excrutiatingly slow. Not impossible to run, but I'm hoping for some way to optimize this.

Each dataset consists of around 17.000 rows over 88 columns, with a rather large amount of duplicates between datasets. It's Twitter data, so the status_id variable serves as a good indicator of duplicate rows. I'm using data.table to make the process more efficient. Duplicates are being cleaned out, the dataset just added removed and gc() is called after a dataset is added. I'm suspecting the unique() function to slow down as the dataset grows, so chunking this process might be an option here. But maybe there's something else that I'm not seeing?

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "dataset_*")

full_data <- data.table()

for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
  load(filenames[i]) 
  print(paste(i, "/", length(filenames), ":", filenames[i]))  # indicates current dataset as number of total datasets
  dataset <- as.data.table(get(ls(pattern="dataset_"))) 
  full_data <- rbind(full_data, dataset)   # add new dataset
  rm(list=ls(pattern="dataset_"))  # remove dataset
  full_data  <- unique(full_data, fromLast = T, by="status_id")  #remove duplicate tweets in data
  gc(verbose = F)  # call gc to clear out RAM 
}
```

Any input on the issue welcome, I'm trying to get into a habit of making my R code as efficient as possible :)

Comment: Are these all `.Rdata` files? Why not first figure out in which dataset and row each `status_id` is seen, and then filter the datasets prior to binding? Something like: `rbind(full_data, dataset[!(dataset$id %in% full_data$id)])`

Comment: Unless you are encountering an issue with memory - calling gc() can take a second or two on each loop. I'd try using something like `purr::map_dfr(filenames, vroom::vroom)` and removing duplicates after - but I'm not a master with efficiency. EDIT: you would need to add `full.names = T` as an argument to  `list.files()` for this to work correctly

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of `data.table`, but the structure of your code looks very similar to the common pitfall of not pre-allocating an array before appending to in an a loop. Optimization is often data dependent, but I would try pre-allocating the size of `full_data` or using `purrr::map` to create a list and then batch combine them. `purrr::reduce` may more closely resemble what your code does now and may be worth trying as well

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've not worked with purrr before, so I'll definetly check that out and try to optimize there. Pre-allocating size seems like a smart move here. 

I'm a bit wary towards filtering before combining, fearing data loss of time critical duplicates - e.g. I'd need to make sure I have the latest instance of a tweet to make sure I have the most up-to-date like count. But since the datasets are named by date, going through them from the back might be an easy fix here.

Comment: vroom sounds very promising, but doesn't seem to work with actual RDa files - or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've done some tinkering and come to a first solution. Batch combining the datasets with rbindlist indeed proved to be a great efficiency boost.

I believe this does have to do mostly with the pre-allocation of size that rbindlist does automatically. I was struggling a bit with finding an elegant way to pre-allocate the dataset that did not involve hand-naming all 88 columns and wildly guessing the final size of the dataset (due to the removal of duplicates in the process). So I didn't benchmark the rbindlist solution against an rbind solution with pre-allocated dataset size.

So here's a solution for batching the files and combining them via rbindlist. The process of combining all 858 datasets onto an initial dataset of ~236000 tweets of an initial search clocked in at 909.68 system.time() and a dataset of ~2.5 million rows.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "dataset_*") 
   
full_data <- as.data.table(data_init)
    
  for (i in seq(1,length(filenames),13)){  # sequence into batches (here: 13)
    files <- filenames[i:(i+12)] # loop through the batched files to load 
    for (j in 1:length(files)) {
      load(files[j])
      print(paste((i+j-1), "/", length(filenames), ":", files[j]))} # indicates current dataset as number of total datasets
    full_data <- rbindlist(mget(c(ls(pattern="dataset"), ls(pattern="full_data"))))   # add new datasets
    print("- batch combined -")
    rm(list=ls(pattern="dataset"))  # remove data
    full_data <- unique(full_data, fromLast = T, by="status_id")  #remove duplicate tweets in data
  }
```

I've divided them into batches of 13, since that evens out nicely with the 858 datasets. Some testing showed that batches of ~8 datasets might be more efficient. Not sure what would be an elegant way to deal with the number of files not evening out with the batches though.

Answer (score 2):

A nicer way to do this could be to process the datasets in batches rather than iteratively. You could pass `l` a `list` of multiple data.tables and bind them together simultaneously with `rbindlist`. Then you'd `setkeyv` to set the key for the `data.table` object. Calling `unique.data.table` on a `data.table` with a set key should be faster, but it may be equivalent to your use of `by`.

```
l <- list(full_data, data)
full_data <- rbindlist(l)
setkeyv(full_data, "status_id")
full_data <- unique(full_data)
```

Comment: Is there a substantial difference between rbind and rbindlist for data.tables? I assumed there was a data.table method for rbind, with rbidndlist being a convenience function for lists. My intitial method for smaller amounts of data was using rbindlist for all the data at once. Quite fast, but I've run into memory issues for this case with all the data being loaded at once.

And I'll give unique with keys a go, that sounds promising. Thanks!

Comment: There is difference, better use rbindlist but split your list into chunks, so use rbindlist few times rather than `n` times using `rbind`.